# forwards algorithm - derivation

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I am self-studying hidden markov models, and am struggling to with the derivation of the forward algorithm, and especially the definition of $\alpha_t$ as the hadamard product. It would be much appreciated if someone can share pointer on where the $\Psi(i,j)=p(z_t=j|z_{t-1}=i)$ comes from. In the formula of alpha (17.46) - the first term is multiplied by  $p(z_t=j|x_{1:t-1}=i)$, and i am struggling to see how in 17.48 we are multiplying with  $\Psi(i,j)=p(z_t=j|z_{t-1}=i)$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is too late.
What you need to do is substitute (17.44) for the last term of equation (17.46) i.e. $p(z_t=j\mid x_{1:t-1})$.

Then $\alpha_t(j) = \frac{1}{Z_t}p(x_t\mid z_t=j)\left(\sum\limits_ip(z_t=j\mid z_{t-1}=i)p(z_{t-1}=i\mid x_{1:t-1})\right)$.

Now if you take $\bf{\alpha}_t$ as the vector with K components and each element being $\alpha_t(j)$, the summation of the above equation can be written as a matrix multiplication $\bf{\Psi}^T\bf{\alpha}_{t-1}$ which yields a vector. $\mathbf{\Psi}$ is defined as in the last paragraph of the text. To get $\mathbf{\alpha}_t$ we need elementwise multiplication between $\bf{\Psi}^T\bf{\alpha}_{t-1}$ and $\psi_t$. Note that $\psi_t$ is again a vector with $j^{th}$ element being $p(x_t\mid z_t=j)$. This elementwise multiplication is denoted as Hadamard product in the text. Then we can arrive at the equation (17.48).